# wordpress walker add class to submenu a href

Tags: menus

I am having some troubles with my wordpress walker code.  I know it's possible to add a custom css class manually via the admin menu section. But what i am trying to achieve is to get this done automatically whenever a submenu page is added by my client.

The first step i took was to replace the ul li navigation and change it to an a href navigational style. This works. Now i am looking for a way to add a class to the submenu a href items...

This is how my walker looks like at the moment.

class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
    {
        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        !empty ( $class_names ) and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
        $output .= "";
        $attributes  = '';
        !empty( $item->attr_title ) and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
        !empty( $item->target ) and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
        !empty( $item->xfn ) and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
        !empty( $item->url ) and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        $item_output = $args->before
        . ""
        . $args->link_before
        . $title
        . ''
        . $args->link_after
        . $args->after;

```
            if (array_search('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes)) {
            $output .= sprintf("\n<div data-delay='0' class='w-dropdown'><div class='dropdown-toggle'><div class='icon icon-dropdown-toggle'></div><div>$title</div></div>
            \n", ( array_search('current-menu-item', $item->classes) || array_search('current-page-parent', $item->classes) ) ? 'active' : '', $item->url,
             $item->title);
        } else {

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }
}

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth, $args ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "\n$indent<nav class=\"dropdown-list\">\n<div class=\"submenu_speech\"></div>";
    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth, $args = array() ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "$indent</nav></div>\n";
    }

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
            $output .= "\n";
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are special filters for adding classes to the `ul`, `li`, or `a` tags in a menu.

For the `a` tags you want to use `nav_menu_link_attributes`. This allows you to modify all attributes on the `a` tag, so here's an example:

```
function my_nav_menu_link_attributes( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    if ( 'main' === $args->theme_location ) {
        if ( '0' === $item->menu_item_parent ) {
            $atts['class'] = 'top-level-item';
        } 
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'my_nav_menu_link_attributes', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: hmm, this should work indeed. But nothing happens. No error, but the class isn't added to any a tag...

Comment: Can you add the version of my code you're using to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
    {
        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;
```

```
    if( $depth == 1 ){
      $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
      !empty ( $class_names ) and $class_names = ' class="dropdown-link w-dropdown-link '. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
    } else {
      $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
      !empty ( $class_names ) and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
    }

    $output .= "";
    $attributes  = '';
    !empty( $item->attr_title ) and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
    !empty( $item->target ) and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
    !empty( $item->xfn ) and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
    !empty( $item->url ) and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';
    $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
    $item_output = $args->before
    . "<a $attributes $class_names>"
    . $args->link_before
    . $title
    . '</a>'
    . $args->link_after
    . $args->after;

            if (array_search('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes)) {
            $output .= sprintf("\n<div data-delay='0' class='w-dropdown'><div class='dropdown-toggle w-dropdown-toggle'><div class='icon w-icon-dropdown-toggle'></div><div>$title</div></div>
            \n", ( array_search('current-menu-item', $item->classes) || array_search('current-page-parent', $item->classes) ) ? 'active' : '', $item->url,
             $item->title);
        } else {

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }
}

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth, $args ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "\n$indent<nav class=\"dropdown-list w-dropdown-list\">\n<div class=\"submenu_speech\"></div>";
    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth, $args = array() ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "$indent</nav></div>\n";
    }

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
            $output .= "\n";
    }
```

}

So when $depth==1 class 'dropdown-link w-dropdown-link' is added to the a tag.

It works, but is this a legit solution?